# Should the trivial solution be included when solving roots of complex numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am thinking about the number of solutions to the problem: $\lvert z\rvert=z^5$ over the field of complex numbers. Usually when faced with solving roots of complex numbers, the number of solutions is simply equal to the degree of the polynomial. However, here, apparently the number of solutions is 6, not 5. How can this be?

Answer (score 2):

When you include absolute value in the formula, it is no longer a polynomial.  (The same if you include complex conjugate).  So the rule doesn't apply.
An example that only involves real numbers:
$$|x^2-4x|=1\\
x^2-4x=\pm1\\
x=2\pm\sqrt{3},2\pm\sqrt{5}$$
so it looks quadratic, but has four roots.

Comment: Ok. But then how would you go about finding the number of roots?

Comment: It depends on the question.  Here, I might take absolute values, so $|z|^5=|z|$  This is a polynomial equation for $|z|$, that is $y^5=y$, and has the five roots $0,1,-1,i,-i$.  Since $|z|\geq0$, $|z|=0,1$.  So there are two possible equations: $z^5=0$, with one root; and $z^5=1$, with five roots.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first take absolute value of both sides to find out what $|z|$ is.  Then the problem simplifies...